# Why Mongoose doesn't validate empty document?

Tags: node.js, validation, mongoose

Let's say I have a very simple schema with a custom validation function that always returns false.

```
var MofoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String
});

MofoSchema.path('name').validate(function (value) {
  console.log("I'm validating");
  return false;
}, 'No pasaran');

mongoose.model('Mofo', MofoSchema);
```

Then I create a new instance of my document and I validate it:

```
var Mofo = mongoose.model('Mofo');
var mofo = new Mofo({name: "Tarte flambée"});

mofo.validate(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Perfect, the custom validator function is called and `err` is filled.

But now I do the same **with no data**:

```
var Mofo = mongoose.model('Mofo');
var mofo = new Mofo({});

mofo.validate(function(err) {
  console.log(err);
});
```

The **custom validator function is not called** and `err` is undefined.
Why? I don't understand why Mongoose is not running the custom validator.

Is this behaviour by design? Is it a bug?
Should I hack a turnaround? Should I check manually for empty data before validation?

Am I doing something wrong?

PS: If you call `save`, the document will be saved as empty in MongoDB despite of the custom validator.

Answer (score 3):

I think mongoose will only validate for existing field.

So you can use 'null' value to activate validation

```
var mofo = new Mofo({name: null});
```

For empty or undefined

```
var MofoSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true}
});

MofoSchema.path('name').validate(function (value) {...}, 'no pasaran');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
var mofo = new Mofo({ name: { type: String, default: ''} });
```

This will ensure you always have a value on that key to trigger validation. It also makes your schema definition easier to read.